Von Neumann Algebras and their Projections
I have three questions about the relationship between von Neumann algebras and the projections which they contain. In what follows, let $H$ be a Hilbert space, let $B(H)$ be the set of bounded operators on $H$, and let $X\subseteq B(H)$ and $Y\subseteq B(H)$ be von Neumann algebras. Also, define a `trivial projection' as a projection which is contained in every single von Neumann algebra of bounded operators on $H$.
Question 1
What are the trivial projections?
My guess is that the only trivial projections, in the sense defined above, are the zero projection and the identity projection: because, I'm guessing, the zero projection and the identity projection generate a von Neumann algebra which doesn't contain any other projections. Is that correct, and if not, what are the other projections which every such von Neumann algebra contains?
Question 2
Suppose that $X\nsubseteq Y$. Then does there exist a non-trivial projection $p\in X$ such that $p\notin Y$?
My guess is that the answer is `yes'. It is often claimed that von Neumann algebras are generated by their projections. For instance, see here, or see Kadison and Ringrose, 1983, p. 326 (Fundamentals of the Theory of Operator Algebras, Vol. 1). But I'm not familiar enough with this subject to be sure that, from the colloquial claim "von Neumann algebras are generated by their projections," the affirmative answer to Question 2 follows. Any details which can be provided about how the affirmative answer follows (if indeed it does) would be greatly appreciated; and the more elementary the details, the better.
Question 3
Suppose that $X$ is generated by a single projection $p\in B(H)$, and suppose that $Y\subseteq X$. In addition, suppose that there exists a non-trivial projection $q\in Y$. Then is it the case that $Y=X$?
My guess is that the answer is `yes'. My very rough reasoning goes like this.

The only non-trivial projections in $X$ are $p$ and $I-p$, where $I$
is the identity projection.
So $q=p$ or $q=I-p$.
Either way, any von Neumann algebra containing $q$ will also contain $p$.
Therefore, $p\in Y$, and so $X\subseteq Y$.

Is this reasoning correct? In particular, I am not sure that step 1 holds. Again, any details which can be provided about the truth of step 1 (if indeed it is true) would be greatly appreciated; and the more elementary the details, the better.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The answers to all your three questions are correct.


You are mostly correct, with a caveat that depends on how you define "von Neumann". The problem is the identity element of the algebra. If your definition of vN algebra is "$M''=M$" then yes, because the identity of $M$ ismthe identity of $H$. But if your definition is "wot/sot closed $*$-subalgebra of $B(H)$" then you allow for different identity elements. With this interpretation (allowing $M$ to be degenerate), $\mathbb Cp$ is a von Neumann algebra for any projection $p$. With this latter point of view, the only trivial projection is $0$.

It is a consequence of the Spectral Theorem that a von Neumann algebra is the norm-closure of the span of its projections. So if every projection of $X$ is in $Y$, the $X\subset Y$.

Your reasoning is correct.



Got it, thanks. Given the definition of a von Neumann algebra, of bounded operators on H, as being a *-subalgebra that's closed with respect to the weak/strong operator topologies, there will be von Neumann algebras whose identities are not the identity of B(H), for instance, those von Neumann algebras generated by various lone projections.

Yes. More importantly, "corners" are ever present in the theory; that is, given a vN algebra $M$ and a projection $p\in M$, you consider the vN algebra $pMp$. With the double commutant definition, $pMp$ would not be a vN algebra, for its double commutant is $pMp+\mathbb C(1-p)$.
